# Shopify: ajax-cart-template isn't showing tags for all products, It is only showing tags for last product

Tags: shopify

I am trying to limit the amount that people can purchase of a product. I am using tags to do this on the cart, collection and product pages. But for some reason it doesn't work on the ajax-cart-template page.

In the {{#items}} I just

```
{% endraw %}

{{ product.tags }}

{% raw %}
```

It works fine with one products, but when I add a second it will only show the uppermost products tags. And then repate the tags for the second product with the same tags.

Comment: Why are you using tags? Why don't you use cart total amount?

Comment: How do I then differentiate which product only allows one per order, and then one that they can order multiples of?

Comment: Then you should go for tags. Problem of tags is they're visible to visitors/customers. I'd suggest using metafields: if variant in cart has metafield 1, only allow 1 line of this variant in cart, else no limit.

Comment: I am trying not to use metafields for this. I am trying to use if max_1 tag as the limiter to the product. It works elsewhere in shopify, but for some reason it doesn't work properly in ajax-cart-template for some reason. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Who were you, @westondeboer? What did you see!?